# How do I match two conditions to return a value without a helper column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on a pretty big data set. It's got two sheets. The first one contains the name of one city and multiple ID numbers. The second sheet should be left alone/unedited (raw data). It contains multiple cities and multiple ID numbers (some of them are in the first sheet and some are not).

I want something like: if city in sheet 1 and ID number in sheet 1 is in sheet 2, then return "Ok". Preferably without any helper columns.

An example:
Sheet1
City      ID       Status,
Londen    12345    OK,
          12346    OK,

Sheet 2
City      ID,
Londen    12345,
Mumbai    12333,
Londen    12346,

I've tried something like

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!A:B,MATCH(B2,Sheet2!B:B,0),0)
```

But I have not figured out yet how to add another condition and add the "OK".
I thought of using VLOOKUP, but I got stuck there too since I don't want to use helper columns

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use countifs to return ok.

Comment: I would recommend using something like =if(and(not(isna(vlookup(....))),not(isna(vlookup(....)))),"ok","other value"), where the vlookup functions would be used to search for the codes in the ranges

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SUMPRODUCT** function to check if both criteria are met in your Sheet 1. i.e. `City = Londen` and `ID is shown on Sheet 2`.

In my solution I have named the City column in Sheet 2 as **Master_City**, and named the ID column in Sheet 2 as **Master_ID**.

Presume you have the city name in cell A2 on Sheet 1, and ID is listed in Column B, then you can use the following formula to get the result:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((Master_City=$A$2)*(Master_ID=B2))>0,"Ok","No Match")
```

Please note I have changed your example data a little bit to test the result. And I have set "No Match" for ID that is missing on Sheet 2. You can show a blank cell by replace `"Na Match"` in the formula with `""` if needed.

You can read the following article regarding the use of **SUMPRODUCT** in varies situations to help to understand my answer better.

[Master Excel’s SUMPRODUCT Formula](https://www.xelplus.com/excel-sumproduct-formula-easy-explanation/)

See below screenshot for more clarifications. Let me know if you still have any questions.
[image: Solution]

Cheers :)